# Rename *.po to *.mo in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, translation, rename

I need to convert all the *.po translation files in the *./lang/* folder to *.mo files.
In Makefile's "i18n" target, I have written:

```
i18n:
@for file in $(wildcard ./lang/*.po); do\
    msgfmt $$file -o $(subst po,mo,$$file); \
done
```

However, this code does not work; moreover, all the *.po files get damaged.

There are 3 files in the folder, and for each of them I get:

```
./lang/uk_UK.po:1:2: syntax error
./lang/uk_UK.po:2: line terminator inside the line
./lang/uk_UK.po:3: Unknown key word «G»
./lang/uk_UK.po:4: Unknown key word «P»
./lang/uk_UK.po:5: Unknown key word «A»
./lang/uk_UK.po:6: Unknown key word «Z»
./lang/uk_UK.po:9: line terminator inside the line
./lang/uk_UK.po:10: Unknown key word «Report»
./lang/uk_UK.po:11: Unknown key word «POT»
./lang/uk_UK.po:12: Unknown key word «PO»
./lang/uk_UK.po:13: Unknown key word «Last»
./lang/uk_UK.po:14: Unknown key word «Language»
./lang/uk_UK.po:15: Unknown key word «Language»
./lang/uk_UK.po:16: Unknown key word «MIME»
./lang/uk_UK.po:17: Unknown key word «Content»
./lang/uk_UK.po:18: Unknown key word «Content»
./lang/uk_UK.po:19: Unknown key word «Entangle»
./lang/uk_UK.po:20: Unknown key word «AES»
```

So, the command seems to modify files before msgfmt gets them.

I have spent lots of time trying different solutions. There are three types of problems I got:

1) Syntax errors - incorrect loop

2) Incorrect substitution

3) Broken translation files

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Define "does not work". Any error in the build log?

Comment: No error, no response - just broken translation files.

Comment: Oh, actually, there are errors! See them in the question.

Comment: The problem seesms to be in this code part: $(subst po,mo,$$file)

Comment: `$(subst)` is a make function. You are trying to use it on a shell variable in shell context. That doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed incorrect heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mixing make functions (and make context) with shell functionality/variables (and shell context).

```
i18n:
    @for file in $(wildcard ./lang/*.po); do\
        msgfmt $$file -o $(subst po,mo,$$file); \
    done
```

The `$(wildcard)` and `$(subst)` functions are expanded at make parse time (or variable expansion time as appropriate). The shell for loop operates at shell execution time.

So while your `$(wildcard)` executes correctly before the shell script runs (and gives your `for` loop something to operate over) and thus works correctly (sort of) the `$(subst)` call *also* executes before the shell script runs and as such operates on the literal value `$$file` and not the expansion of the shell variable `$file`.

In this context, as it turns out, you likely want **neither** `$(wildcard)` **or** `$(subst)` and instead want something like this:

```
.PHONY: i18n
i18n:
    @for file in ./lang/*.po; do\
        msgfmt $$file -o "$${file/%po/mo}"; \
    done
```

The `.PHONY: i18n` line is necessary to make sure that make target works correctly should an `i18n` file ever be created by anything.

If the `"$${file/%po/mo}"` expansion fails then using `"$${foo%po}mo"` should work instead. The `//` expansion (for pattern replacement) might be a bash-ism but the `%` expansion (for suffix removal) is POSIX.

That all being said though you may, in fact, want to use something more like this:

```
.PHONY: i18n
i18n: $(PO_FILES:po=mo)

%.mo: %.po
    msgfmt $< -o $@
```

To let make do the "does this `.mo` file need updating" checking/etc. and to more effectively use what make does for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of this methods work. The first one produces "bad substitution" error, and the other one - "mixed implicit and static samples. Stop."

Comment: Bleh, typo on the second one. Sorry about that. Fixing. The first one should have worked though I think... unless `/bin/sh` doesn't support that expansion on your system which is possible. Adding an alternate for that.

Comment: Well... Maybe I did something wrong, but this code doesn't work:
`.PHONY: i18n
i18n:
 @for file in ./lang/*.po; do\
  msgfmt $$file -o "$${file/%po}mo"; \
 done`
Bad substitution again. If I remove one dollar sign, it saves translations to a file, named "mo". The second variant worked.

Comment: There's no `/` in the the alternate expansion for the first version. Just `%`. The second variant is better anyway though.